# Jquery Ajax and MVC5 httpPost no value received

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I try to send values from my view to my controller.
The method in my controller is called but the value(s) still remain NULL.

**Here is the Javascript part:**

```
GUIRequests.prototype.SetNewItemDeliveryValues = function () {
    var modelNumberID = this.GetValue('#ModelNumberID');

    this.Request.GetPreOrderIDForModelNumberID(modelNumberID); //InventValueRequest
    this.Request.GetShortfallAndOverdeliveryInNewItemDelivery(modelNumberID);
}

InventValueRequest.prototype.GetPreOrderIDForModelNumberID = function (_modelNumberID) {
    this.CallAjax("/NewItemDelivery/GetPreOrderIDForModelNumberID", _modelNumberID, CallbackMethods.SetPreOrderID);
}

//Private
InventValueRequest.prototype.CallAjax = function (_url, _data, _successFunctionPointer) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(_data),
        success: _successFunctionPointer,
        error: InventValueRequest.HandleError
    });
}
```

**Asp.Net MVC5 (C#) part**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetPreOrderIDForModelNumberID(string _modelnumberID)
    {
        String preOrderID = "";
        if (_modelnumberID == null)
        {
            preOrderID = "No value received";
        }
        else 
        {
            //Do something
        }

        return Json(preOrderID);
    }
```

What could be the problem with my code ? why don't I receive any values in my C# part ? It seems that the values get send correctly, at least the payload contains the values I would expect.

Comment: Does `_data` has the property `_modelnumberID`?

Comment: Nope, that was the problem :/ now i feel very stupid. Thanks a lot that solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_data` should have the property `_modelnumberID` like following.

```
 _data = {'_modelnumberID': '1'}
```

Comment: I made an object with an property _modelNumberId and set its value then JSON stringified it but you are right my object should have a property

Answer (score 1):

try below code :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: _url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: "_modelnumberID=" + _data,
        success: _successFunctionPointer,
        error: InventValueRequest.HandleError
    });
```

Comment: it means your _data does not have any value.@Bongo

Answer (score 1):

The Ideal solution would be to use a view model.

```
public class Create
{
public string _modelnumberID{get;set;}
}
```

And your HttpPost action would be accepting an object of this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult View(Create model)
{
  // do something and return something
}
```

and ajax will be

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
var myData = {
    _modelnumberID: _data
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/Action',
    type: 'POST',
    data: myData,
    processData: false  
}).done(function () {

}).fail(function () {

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _url+"?_modelnumberID="+ _data,
        success: _successFunctionPointer,
        error: InventValueRequest.HandleError
    });
```

Try this.

Comment: He try to send data as post by doing that data will send as get

Comment: Would you like to elaborate how exactly? I put a HttpPost filter on my controller method and it still worked.